# JavaScript - How to show the next div and hide the previous one?

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating a simple quiz and would like to know how to show one question at a time but only using JavaScript. I do not know jQuery. Essentially, I would like the first question to be shown automatically.

Here is an example of what my HTML looks like:

```
<div id="q0">
   <li>
      <h3>1. The color of the sky is... </h3>
      <input type="radio" name="question0" value="A">Green<br>
      <input type="radio" name="question0" value="B">Blue<br>
      <input type="radio" name="question0" value="C">Red<br>
      <input type="radio" name="question0" value="D">Purple<br>
   </li>
</div>
<div id="q1"  style="visibility:hidden">
   <li>
      <h3>2. Paper comes from... </h3>
      <input type="radio" name="question1" value="A">Water<br>
      <input type="radio" name="question1" value="B">Cement<br>
      <input type="radio" name="question1" value="C">Trees<br>
      <input type="radio" name="question1" value="D">The Sky<br>
   </li>
</div>
<div id="q2"  style="visibility:hidden">
   <li>
      <h3>3. How many hours in a day? </h3>
      <input type="radio" name="question2" value="A">24<br>
      <input type="radio" name="question2" value="B">22<br>
      <input type="radio" name="question2" value="C">16<br>
      <input type="radio" name="question2" value="D">48<br>
   </li>
</div>
```

I currently don't have script for showing next div and hiding the previous one because I don't know how to even start.

I'm looking to have it put into this form...

```
function nextQ(){
  // code
}
```

... and for it to be called by this button:

```
<button onclick="next()">Next Question</button>
```

I am really new to HTML and JavaScript and would appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Comment: you can better use jquery for doing this easily, you want to try jquery?

Comment: @FrebinFrancis I guess I could try JQuery, but I would prefer JavaScript because it is something I am familiar with.

Comment: if you are looking for javascript then     document.getElementById("divid").style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById("divid").style.display = 'none';

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV could you show me how I could make that work in my code?

Comment: @MarkD Does this helps... http://jsfiddle.net/z1oweuka/

Comment: @MarkD Already Rakesh_Kumar give an answer, i think that will help you , if not let me know

Comment: Rakesh_Kumar's answer is only in javascript and is a better implementation that mine ;)

Comment: @josh.chavanne I am actually in school right now and haven't learned jQuery yet... And yes, this is for an assignment. I'll mention that next time. It's just that I don't want to put in code I don't understand into my work. What's the point of pretending I know what I'm doing if it'll just bite me in the ass later. Thanks for taking your time into this.

Comment: I've included both versions in my answer (mostly because I accidentally wrote the jQuery version first, lol). Hope it helps.

Comment: @Rakesh_Kumar your code makes sense to me but for some reason it's not working in my code. I'm going to look at the other answers and hope those help me understand. Thanks.

Comment: @MarkD Probably because you might forgot to add some changes in HTML too...

Comment: @MarkD make sure the button's 'click' event and the function are named the same thing.  In Rakesh_Kumar's code - he changed the function name from 'nextQ' to 'next' to match your button.  Make sure the button is calling the EXACT same function name.

Comment: Thank you everyone for responding so quickly on my question. I did trial and error for all of your solutions and have chose to use the one I feel most comfortable with. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pure JavaScript version (config):

```js
var showing = [1, 0, 0];
var questions = ['q0', 'q1', 'q2'];
function next() {
    var qElems = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {
        qElems.push(document.getElementById(questions[i]));   
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < showing.length; i++) {
        if (showing[i] == 1) {
            qElems[i].style.display = 'none';
            showing[i] = 0;
            if (i == showing.length - 1) {
                qElems[0].style.display = 'block';
                showing[0] = 1;
            } else {
                qElems[i + 1].style.display = 'block';
                showing[i + 1] = 1;
            }
            break;
        }
    }      
}
```

```html
<div id="questions">
<div id="q0">
<h3>1. The color of the sky is... </h3>
<input type="radio" name="question0" value="A">Green<br>
<input type="radio" name="question0" value="B">Blue<br>
<input type="radio" name="question0" value="C">Red<br>
<input type="radio" name="question0" value="D">Purple<br>
</div>
<div id="q1"  style="display: none">
<h3>2. Paper comes from... </h3>
<input type="radio" name="question1" value="A">Water<br>
<input type="radio" name="question1" value="B">Cement<br>
<input type="radio" name="question1" value="C">Trees<br>
<input type="radio" name="question1" value="D">The Sky<br>
</div>
<div id="q2"  style="display: none">
<h3>3. How many hours in a day? </h3>
<input type="radio" name="question2" value="A">24<br>
<input type="radio" name="question2" value="B">22<br>
<input type="radio" name="question2" value="C">16<br>
<input type="radio" name="question2" value="D">48<br>
</div>
</div>
    
<button onclick="next()">Next Question</button>
```

---

Pure JavaScript version (no config):

```js
function next() {
    var qElems = document.querySelectorAll('#questions>div');
    for (var i = 0; i < qElems.length; i++) {
        if (qElems[i].style.display != 'none') {
            qElems[i].style.display = 'none';
            if (i == qElems.length - 1) {
                qElems[0].style.display = 'block';
            } else {
                qElems[i + 1].style.display = 'block';
            }
            break;
        }
    }      
}
```

```html
<div id="questions">
<div id="q0">
<h3>1. The color of the sky is... </h3>
<input type="radio" name="question0" value="A">Green<br>
<input type="radio" name="question0" value="B">Blue<br>
<input type="radio" name="question0" value="C">Red<br>
<input type="radio" name="question0" value="D">Purple<br>
</div>
<div id="q1" style="display: none;">
<h3>2. Paper comes from... </h3>
<input type="radio" name="question1" value="A">Water<br>
<input type="radio" name="question1" value="B">Cement<br>
<input type="radio" name="question1" value="C">Trees<br>
<input type="radio" name="question1" value="D">The Sky<br>
</div>
<div id="q2" style="display: none;">
<h3>3. How many hours in a day? </h3>
<input type="radio" name="question2" value="A">24<br>
<input type="radio" name="question2" value="B">22<br>
<input type="radio" name="question2" value="C">16<br>
<input type="radio" name="question2" value="D">48<br>
</div>
</div>
    
<button onclick="next()">Next Question</button>
```

---

jQuery version:

```js
$(function() {
    $('.next').on('click', function() {
        $('#questions>div').each(function() {
            var id = $(this).index();
            if ($(this).is(':visible')) {
                $(this).hide();
                if (id == $('#questions>div').length - 1) {
                    $('#questions>div').eq(0).show();
                } else {
                    $('#questions>div').eq(id + 1).show();
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="questions">
<div id="q0">
<h3>1. The color of the sky is... </h3>
<input type="radio" name="question0" value="A">Green<br>
<input type="radio" name="question0" value="B">Blue<br>
<input type="radio" name="question0" value="C">Red<br>
<input type="radio" name="question0" value="D">Purple<br>
</div>
<div id="q1"  style="display: none">
<h3>2. Paper comes from... </h3>
<input type="radio" name="question1" value="A">Water<br>
<input type="radio" name="question1" value="B">Cement<br>
<input type="radio" name="question1" value="C">Trees<br>
<input type="radio" name="question1" value="D">The Sky<br>
</div>
<div id="q2"  style="display: none">
<h3>3. How many hours in a day? </h3>
<input type="radio" name="question2" value="A">24<br>
<input type="radio" name="question2" value="B">22<br>
<input type="radio" name="question2" value="C">16<br>
<input type="radio" name="question2" value="D">48<br>
</div>
</div>
    
<button class="next">Next Question</button>
```

Comment: why did not use querySelectorAll() ?

Comment: Heh, I didn't even know it existed :) Looks good to go though, http://caniuse.com/#feat=queryselector . Thanks for the tip (I'll probably still never use it, except when giving "JavaScript only" answers on this site).

Comment: your answer is fine, but the problem is when the number of div is huge, and those all divs are created dynamically , may be by user that time we can't predefined the data like id.

Comment: I agree. I was reading up on it (older concerns of browser inconsistencies, etc.) I'm updating my answer. Thanks again :)

Comment: Ok your jquery is nice +1 for that

Comment: Yeah, I don't run a single site without it. Thank you!

Comment: @BitwiseCreative thanks for your answer in both jQuery and JavaScript, hopefully I learn jQuery soon. This code was clear and helpful, thanks. Just one last thing, do you know how I could hide the Next Question button after it reaches it's last question?

Comment: You're very welcome. I got schooled a bit by @Arunprasanth KV about a method I wasn't aware of, so I included that as well (no config JavaScript version). Hiding the button would be easy. I'll just make a fiddle for that with the no config version. Give me a few minutes.

Comment: @MarkD Hide the next question button when last question reaches not a good practice, when you do something like that then your window will be blank , there is no other controls , so just put a previous button when last question reaches, or show an alert message to user the question queue is over something like that , otherwise user will be confused about the sudden disappearance of the button

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV well I didn't show my full code but I actually made it so it shows a final div that tells the user in text that they are done the quiz and that they can view their results by clicking a newly shown button. Thanks for the tip though!

Answer (score 2):

Though I agree with @Bitwise on using jQuery instead on javascript alone to ensure cross-browser compatibility. But since you insist on using javascript, here's what you should do.

1) Ensure that your `<li>`'s are enclosed in a container tag first (say, `<ul>`) so you iterate only through desired list.

2) use `display:none` property instead of `visibility:hidden`. `visibility:hidden` simply hides an element, but it will still take up the same space as before. `display:none` hides an element, and it will not take up any space.

Here's the updated code.

**HTML:**

```
<ul id="listContainer">
<div id="q0">
      <li style="display:list-item">
          <h3>1. The color of the sky is... </h3>
          <input type="radio" name="question0" value="A"/>Green<br/>
          <input type="radio" name="question0" value="B"/>Blue<br/>
          <input type="radio" name="question0" value="C"/>Red<br/>
              <input type="radio" name="question0" value="D"/>Purple<br/>
      </li>
    </div>

    <div id="q1"  >
      <li style="display:none">
        <h3>2. Paper comes from... </h3>
          <input type="radio" name="question1" value="A"/>Water<br/>
          <input type="radio" name="question1" value="B"/>Cement<br/>
          <input type="radio" name="question1" value="C"/>Trees<br/>
              <input type="radio" name="question1" value="D"/>The Sky<br/>
      </li>
    </div>
    <div id="q2" >
      <li  style="display:none">
        <h3>3. How many hours in a day? </h3>
          <input type="radio" name="question2" value="A"/>24<br/>
          <input type="radio" name="question2" value="B"/>22<br/>
          <input type="radio" name="question2" value="C"/>16<br/>
          <input type="radio" name="question2" value="D"/>48<br/>
      </li>
    </div>
</ul>
    <button id="next">next</button>
```

**Javascript:**

```
document.getElementById('next').addEventListener("click",function(){

    var listContainer = document.getElementById("listContainer");
    var listItem = listContainer.getElementsByTagName("li");

    for (var i=0; i < listItem.length-1; i++) 
    {
        if(listItem[i].style.display == "list-item")
        {
            listItem[i].style.display = "none";
            listItem[i+1].style.display = "list-item";
            break;
        }
    }

});
```

Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/59vqnjjy/1/).

Cheers!

Comment: More than one way to skin a cat, right? Interesting approach, well done. +1

Comment: Haha, yes. Thats the beauty of javascript. It allows one to do some many things in so many different ways :)

Answer (score 1):

I would twist the code a little. Add question class to every div which acts as question i.e  .question { display:none }. Add active class to first question (i.e. .active{display:block}, it shows the first question. Look for all divs with question class and add them to a variable, with every next button pressed,remove active class from current question add active class to next div with class question using classList.add and classList.remove of Javascript until last question is reached. Count keeps the current question's number.
I've done it in the codepen http://codepen.io/dwanirdesh/pen/EaQOPg

Or code directly from below:

```
<div id="q0" class="question active">
<li>
<h3>1. The color of the sky is... </h3>
<input type="radio" name="question0" value="A">Green<br>
<input type="radio" name="question0" value="B">Blue<br>
<input type="radio" name="question0" value="C">Red<br>
<input type="radio" name="question0" value="D">Purple<br>
</li>
</div>
<div id="q1" class="question" >
<li>
<h3>2. Paper comes from... </h3>
<input type="radio" name="question1" value="A">Water<br>
<input type="radio" name="question1" value="B">Cement<br>
<input type="radio" name="question1" value="C">Trees<br>
<input type="radio" name="question1" value="D">The Sky<br>
</li>
</div>
<div id="q2"  class="question">
<li>
<h3>3. How many hours in a day? </h3>
<input type="radio" name="question2" value="A">24<br>
<input type="radio" name="question2" value="B">22<br>
<input type="radio" name="question2" value="C">16<br>
<input type="radio" name="question2" value="D">48<br>
</li>
</div>

<button onclick="next()">Next Question</button>

## CSS ##
.question{
  display:none
}

.active{
  display:block
}

## JAVASCRIPT ##

var questionNumber=0;
var questions=document.querySelectorAll('.question');
        function next(){
          questionNumber++;
          if(questions.length>questionNumber)
          {
                document.querySelector('.active').classList.remove('active');
                questions[questionNumber].classList.add('active');
          }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the java script function code. For this to work, you need to make sure that the div display property to be set as  or  in the html code.  Also you need to name the id of the button to be "next"  so that it can be hidden on reaching the last button.

```
function nextQ(){
   var  blockFound = 0;
   var lastQuestion = 0;
   var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
   for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++){
   if ( blockFound == 1){
    blockFound = 0;
    divs[i].style.display = 'block'; 
    }else if ( divs[i].style.display == 'block' ){
    if ( i + 2 == divs.length){
        lastQuestion = 1;
    }
    blockFound = 1;
   divs[i].style.display = 'none'; 
   }
 }
if ( lastQuestion == 1){
    document.getElementById('next').style.visibility = 'hidden';  
   }  
 }
```

Html code here.

```
<div id="q0" style="display:block">
<li>
<h3>1. The color of the sky is... </h3>
<input type="radio" name="question0" value="A">Green<br>
<input type="radio" name="question0" value="B">Blue<br>
<input type="radio" name="question0" value="C">Red<br>
<input type="radio" name="question0" value="D">Purple<br>
</li>
</div>
<div id="q1"  style="display:none">
<li>
<h3>2. Paper comes from... </h3>
<input type="radio" name="question1" value="A">Water<br>
<input type="radio" name="question1" value="B">Cement<br>
<input type="radio" name="question1" value="C">Trees<br>
<input type="radio" name="question1" value="D">The Sky<br>
</li>
</div>
<div id="q2"  style="display:none">
<li>
<h3>3. How many hours in a day? </h3>
<input type="radio" name="question2" value="A">24<br>
<input type="radio" name="question2" value="B">22<br>
<input type="radio" name="question2" value="C">16<br>
<input type="radio" name="question2" value="D">48<br>
</li>
</div>
<button id="next" onclick="nextQ()">Next Question</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

Is it what you need?

```
  <div id="q0">
  <li>
  <h3>1. The color of the sky is... </h3>
  <input type="radio" name="question0" value="A">Green<br>
  <input type="radio" name="question0" value="B">Blue<br>
  <input type="radio" name="question0" value="C">Red<br>
  <input type="radio" name="question0" value="D">Purple<br>
  </li>
  <button class="next" onclick="goNext(0)">Next Question</button>
  </div>

  <div id="q1"  style="display:none">
  <li>
  <h3>2. Paper comes from... </h3>
  <input type="radio" name="question1" value="A">Water<br>
  <input type="radio" name="question1" value="B">Cement<br>
  <input type="radio" name="question1" value="C">Trees<br>
  <input type="radio" name="question1" value="D">The Sky<br>
  </li>
  <button class="next" onclick="goNext(1)">Next Question</button>
  </div>

  <div id="q2"  style="display:none">
  <li>
  <h3>3. How many hours in a day? </h3>
  <input type="radio" name="question2" value="A">24<br>
  <input type="radio" name="question2" value="B">22<br>
  <input type="radio" name="question2" value="C">16<br>
  <input type="radio" name="question2" value="D">48<br>
  </li>
  <button class="next" onclick="goNext(2)">Next Question</button>
  </div>

  <script language=javascript>
      function goNext(i)
      {
          document.getElementById("q"+i).style.display = 'none'; 
          i++;
          document.getElementById("q"+i).style.display = 'block'; 
      }
  </script>
```