# Show next div when button pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create a list with five list items. By default there is only the first item shown and if i press a button "Next one" it shows next list item (and so on).

After reaching to the last item button shoud be disabled because there is no list items left.

How can i achieve this kind of behavior?

I have found this example here: [JavaScript - show next div and hide previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28535226/javascript-show-next-div-and-hide-previous)
but this one hides previous one.

Maybe it can be combined with "addclass" function to add class ul siblings that haveent got a class?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Can you post your code? Any html, or JS?

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried?

Comment: Because i'm not fluent in Js or Jquery this custom show nth item after last one is too difficult for me. I have tried it with addclass function but this is not the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According with the link you attach, if you use the same code and removes the line `qElems[i].style.display = 'none';` it works as you like. But will be better if you learn javascript before coding.

Complete example (extracted from [JavaScript - show next div and hide previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28535226/javascript-show-next-div-and-hide-previous) with some editions )

```js
var showing = [1, 0, 0];
var questions = ['q0', 'q1', 'q2'];
function next() {
    var qElems = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {
        qElems.push(document.getElementById(questions[i]));   
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < showing.length; i++) {
        if (showing[i] == 1) {
            showing[i] = 0;
            if (i == showing.length - 1) {
                document.getElementById("buttonNext").disabled = "disabled";
            } else {
                qElems[i + 1].style.display = 'block';
                showing[i + 1] = 1;
            }
            break;
        }
    }      
}
```

```html
<div id="questions">
<div id="q0">
<h3>1. The color of the sky is... </h3>
<input type="radio" name="question0" value="A">Green<br>
<input type="radio" name="question0" value="B">Blue<br>
<input type="radio" name="question0" value="C">Red<br>
<input type="radio" name="question0" value="D">Purple<br>
</div>
<div id="q1"  style="display: none">
<h3>2. Paper comes from... </h3>
<input type="radio" name="question1" value="A">Water<br>
<input type="radio" name="question1" value="B">Cement<br>
<input type="radio" name="question1" value="C">Trees<br>
<input type="radio" name="question1" value="D">The Sky<br>
</div>
<div id="q2"  style="display: none">
<h3>3. How many hours in a day? </h3>
<input type="radio" name="question2" value="A">24<br>
<input type="radio" name="question2" value="B">22<br>
<input type="radio" name="question2" value="C">16<br>
<input type="radio" name="question2" value="D">48<br>
</div>
</div>
    
<button onclick="next()" id="buttonNext">Next Question</button>
```

Comment: Yes, this is what i was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I just made it using jquery:

```js
$(document).on('click','button.next', function(){
  var childID = $('#list li').index($('li.display'));
  $('#list li:eq(' + childID + ')').toggleClass('display')
  $('#list li:eq(' + ( childID + 1 ) + ')').toggleClass('display')
})
```

```css
 li{
  display: none;
}
li.display{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="list">
 <li class="display">1</li>
 <li>2</li>
 <li>3</li>
 <li>4</li>
 <li>5</li>
</ul>
<button class="next">Next One</button>
```

Comment: All previous numbers should be visible after adding next number.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the HTML in which you create a list of five items, with first item is displayed by default and the rest is hidden**.

*html code*

```
<div class='demo'>1</div>
<div class='demo' style='display:none;'>2</div>
<div class='demo' style='display:none;'>3</div>
<div class='demo' style='display:none;'>4</div>

<button class='next'>Next</button>
```

**Here the button in action is `next` whenever you click the next button, it displays the next list item i.e on first click it would display second item and hides the rest. This will go on until the length of your list.**

js code

```
var n = 2
$('.next').click(function(e){
    $('.demo').hide();
    $('.demo:nth-child('+n+')').show();
    var demo_l = $('.demo').length;
    if(n == demo_l){
      $('.next').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
    n++;
});
```

Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4k0t000w/)

Comment: Do you plan on explaining your answer or do you expect people to just copy/paste  and use it without understanding it?

Comment: Let the guy ask if he has the problem in understanding!

Comment: Answers should be explained as this doesn't just help one person. Other  people might have the same issue, search and find your answer.

Comment: All previous numbers should be visible after adding next number.