# multiple questions in one mTurk HIT. creation of next button

Tags: javascript, html, amazon-web-services, nlp, survey

I'm creating a task on mTurck in which I want people to rank sentences on a scale of 1 to 100 according to a simple question.

The problem is that i want every Turker to rank 100 sentences per 1 HIT, since a single sentence per person (or just a dozen or two) is not good enough data for me.

I wish to display one sentence at a time only, and use some kind of "next" button, instead of letting the Turker scroll throw 100 sentences as a single web page (due to convenience reasons). On top of that, I would like the Turker to be able to submit the HIT only after grading all 100 sentences (or some other arbitrary number).

I've created the basic HTML code for a single question, but i don't know how to create a next button that will allow me to let the turker answer the questions one-by-one, without scroling down.

this is a single sentance html code :

```
<!-- You must include this JavaScript file -->
<script src="https://assets.crowd.aws/crowd-html-elements.js"></script>

<!-- You must include crowd-form so that your task submits answers to MTurk -->
<crowd-form answer-format="flatten-objects">

    <p>

        Read the piece of text below and use the slider below indicate how much do you agree with the following statement:


    </p>


    <p><strong>
            A statement(doesn't change) (0 = it doesn't bother me at all, 100 = it   really bothers me): <br></br><br></br>
    </strong>
    ${original_text}
    </p>

     <p>

        <p><crowd-slider style="width: 800px; height: 20px;" name="mistakeRate" min="1" max="100"  required pin/></p>


  </p>
</crowd-form>
```

if you have an idea, or maybe even some other template that will allow me to create the task as i wish, I'll be very grateful.

thanks,
Ofir

Comment: You should be able to use the following: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28535226/javascript-how-to-show-the-next-div-and-hide-the-previous-one

Comment: thanks! 
i did use something similar eventually.